# How do you add in assets to Laravel 4 from the public directory?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to add in assets but I can't seem to find a solid answer online. The {{}} is not interpolating values and is literally being written in my source code. Do you know why? My current hello.php view is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    testing
    <script data-main="{{ URL::asset('public/js/main') }}" src="{{ URL::asset('public/js/require-jquery.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to name your file `filename.blade.php` in order to use the Blade rendering engine.

If you don't want to use Blade, you can just use regular PHP:

```
<script src="<?php echo URL::asset('js/require-jquery.js') ?>"></script>
```

---

**P.S.** Your path is wrong (you don't need the `public/` part).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the public/ and try it again.